# How do I determine if a GPU is available on my OS?

Tags: python, command-line, gpu

People are talking about GPU computing these days. How do I know if a GPU is available on my computer?  I would like to have a python way, or alternatively using a shell command, to know if a GPU is available. I am using Mac OS
Catalina version 10.15 if that matters.

BTW, could I safely assume GPU is available in most computers today?

Comment: tensorflow has a method to show available gpus assuming you use that module

Comment: It's probably fair to assume that a GPU is available on many, but not all systems. However, it may be an integrated GPU (which is physically in the same package as the CPU).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that using the PyTorch library you can determine this. Usually, the [CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-zone) platform is used in order to make the computation on the GPU.

So, in Python you have to do the following:

```
import torch

torch.cuda.is_available()
```

This will return if the GPU/CUDA is available or not.

Then you can do the following to select the device (CPU or GPU)

```
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [This](https://www.howtogeek.com/508993/how-to-check-which-gpu-is-installed-on-linux/#:%7E:text=Using%20the%20GUI%20to%20Identify%20the%20Graphics%20Card&text=In%20fact%2C%20that%20option%20is,for%20a%20%E2%80%9CGraphics%E2%80%9D%20entry.), You should be able to tell if there's a GPU installed by opening the “Settings” dialog, and then click “Details” in the sidebar. In the “About” panel, look for a “Graphics” entry. This tells you what kind of graphics card is in the computer, or, more specifically, the graphics card that’s currently in use. Your machine might have more than one GPU.

Comment: That's not what OP asked though? He asked for either a pythonic way or a shell command.

Comment: The link also provide ways to use the terminal to see if the machine has GPU, that's why i also provided the link not just that solution.